# Sanskrit Resources

Tags: pali-language, pali

I have been using the Pali Digital Reader to learn Pali (it is a wonderful resource!). Does anyone know of any similar resources for sanskrit? An online software/plugin/reader which makes translating from Sanskrit to English easy and quick?

I am studying Sanskrit a lot and spend hours copy pasting words from the sanskrit into the online sanskrit dictionary. I was hoping there is something similar to the Pali Digital Reader out there which would make this process easier?

Any help or advice at all is very much appreciated. Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There’s plenty of great software for Sanskrit ([here](http://indology.info/links/soft/), for example) but I read there is yet anything corresponding to the Pali Digital Reader.

You may also find useful [Digital Corpus of Sanskrit](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php).